# No Release Option

Tags: visual-studio-2015, vs-web-site-project

In VS2015 I do not have a release option for my web site.  If I go to build and configuration manager, no where is release listed.  NOR is it listed when I look at the top of my window in the drop down list, I only have debug and configuration manager.  If I choose configuration manager, their is not a release option in those settings either

Where is the release setting?!

I also used these instructions but I do not have the release option so I was unable to follow it::

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wx0123s5(v=vs.110).aspx)

And this is what my web-config settings look like

```
 <system.web>
   <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>
 </system.web>
```

And I am trying to publish my website by going to

> Publish
>   File System
>   Choosing the location
>   And in the configuration - I only have debug no release option to publish

And this is the youtube video I am following to publish my site on IIS

[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IwbKquNBNgQ)

Comment: I tried using the MSDN tutorial and it was no help.  I have tried googling but not seen any useful information yet.  I just see release date not issues with a release